# Comparing data across multiple tables

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, powerquery

**Background:**
In the image below on the left I have materials A,B...C etc. Each of these materials can come from 3 suppliers (1-3) but because they are different suppliers each material contains various impurities (metals) per material.

[image]

**Problem/So far:**
To simplify I have used power query to split the data into 3 independent tables such that the data is compartmentalized (shown below).

[image]

Now, for each impurity (metal) I wish to compare the metals between the 3 tables and return a list that contains only the highest value as well as the Table Name (supplier) If possible.

This is proving to be quite challenging although I'm sure a similar analysis like this will have been achieved before. Essentially I'm just aiming to compare values across multiple tables to return both the highest value found and its source. If anyone who has done something like this has any advice/solutions it would be appreciated.

Comment: I assume using VBA is not desired?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to have one table with a column for supplier instead of a table for each supplier? You could do that with Power Query by splitting each column by line feed, unpivoting all columns apart from material,  splitting the Attribute column to get the supplier and splitting the value column to get the element/quantity.

Comment: @Amiga500 I'm not hugely familiar with VBA and although any realistic solutions are considered I suppose I would say I am looking for Non VBA solutions. Thanks though.

Comment: @norie I will looks into this and get back to you.

Comment: Range `N7:Q7` of your desired result indicates that the highest gold value is 30 from supplier, but supplier 1 is not supplying gold to A?

Comment: @Terry W Ah yes you’re right. Sorry I typed these results manually just to show the desired output. I will update the photo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit different PQ approach

- Split the original table to create a single row for each item, and separate columns for the metal and the amount
- Use the Table.Group function to extract the highest amount and corresponding supplier for each Material/metal combination

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table5"]}[Content],
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(Source,{{"Column1", "Material"}}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns1",
        {{"Material", type text}, {"1", type text}, {"2", type text}, {"3", type text}}),

//Unpivot to create three columns
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Material"}, "Supplier", "Value"),

//Split the Metals column into rows by line feed to => one row per metal
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {
        {"Value", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("#(lf)", QuoteStyle.Csv), 
        let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Value"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Value", type text}}),

//Split Metals column at the space to => two columns -- one for the name; the other for the amount
    #"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type1", "Value", 
        Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Metal", "Amount"}),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter1",{{"Metal", type text}, {"Amount", Int64.Type}}),

//Group rows by Material and Metal
//Extract the highest amount and corresponding suppler
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type2", {"Material", "Metal"}, {
        {"Amount", each List.Max([Amount]),type number},
        {"Supplier", (t) => t[Supplier]{List.PositionOf(t[Amount],List.Max(t[Amount]))}, type text}
        })
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we start with the top table in powerquery you can transform to the second image using this code:

It does an upivot, a split on linefeed, a split on space, then a rename

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"1", type text}, {"2", type text}, {"3", type text}}),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Column1"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {{"Value", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("#(lf)", QuoteStyle.None), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Value"),
#"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Split Column by Delimiter", "Value", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({" "}, QuoteStyle.None, false), {"Metal", "Amount"}),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter1",{{"Attribute", "Supplier"}, {"Column1", "Material"}})
in #"Renamed Columns"
```

[image]

From there you can add a few more rows to generate the table you wanted based on grouping and taking the maximum, then merging the supplier name

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"1", type text}, {"2", type text}, {"3", type text}}),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Column1"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {{"Value", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("#(lf)", QuoteStyle.None), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Value"),
#"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Split Column by Delimiter", "Value", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({" "}, QuoteStyle.None, false), {"Metal", "Amount"}),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter1",{{"Attribute", "Supplier"}, {"Column1", "Material"}}),
// generate max table
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Renamed Columns", {"Material", "Metal"}, {{"Highest Amount", each List.Max([Amount]), type text}}),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Grouped Rows",{"Material", "Metal", "Highest Amount"},#"Renamed Columns" ,{"Material", "Metal", "Amount"},"Table0",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table0", {"Supplier"}, {"Supplier"}),
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Table1",{{"Highest Amount", type number}})
in  #"Changed Type1"
```

[image]

Comment: For `A-Gold`, you are returning a value of 5 and supplier 2; shouldn't it be 10 and supplier 3?

Comment: Thank you. I have selected the other answer provided as its a bit clearer but this is also a good solution.